# Why isn't my current_user authenticated in flask-login?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, flask, flask-login

My goal is to make my home view (`/`) a login page. Once the user logs in, a different page is render depending on its role. When I login (`/auth`), I see that the username and password are correctly entered. It then attempts to render `/`, where it tells me that my user is not authenticated and renders `/login`. Here are the views that describe this:

## Views

```
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return flask.render_template('login.html')

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        if current_user.is_admin():
            return flask.render_template('admin_index.html')
        return flask.render_template('user_index.html')
    logger.info("Not authenticated. Going back to login.")
    return flask.render_template('login.html')


@app.route("/auth", methods=["POST"])
def auth():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
    logger.info(user)
    logger.info("{0}: {1}".format(username, password))
    print("user exists? {0}".format(str(user != None)))
    print("password is correct? " + str(user.check_password(password)))
    if user and user.check_password(password):
        user.is_authenticated = True
        login_user(user)
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    return flask.redirect(url_for('login'))
```

The problem is that flask-login's `current_user.is_authenticated` is always returning `False` after I attempt to login. My created user is correctly created and committed to the database. Below is my User model with the necessary methods as per flask-login:

## User model

```
class User(db.Model):
    """
    A user. More later.
    """

    __tablename__ = 'User'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    hashed_password = db.Column(db.String(160))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, username, password="changeme123", admin=False):
        self.username = username
        self.set_password(password)
        self.admin = admin
        self.is_authenticated = False

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.is_authenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {0}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.hashed_password = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.hashed_password, password)
```

Here is the `load_user` function:

## load_user

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(User.id==user_id)
    except:
        return None
```

---

Why is `current_user.is_authenticated` returning `False`? I presumed that `login_user(user)` would make `current_user == user`, i.e., the one who is being authenticated in `/auth`, but it seems this is not the case.

Comment: Where is `load_user` defined? Are you sure it's being loaded?

Comment: @dirn `load_user` is defined in the same file as my user model. Should it be defined somewhere in particular? It's being imported into views. My user is correctly loaded.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. It's an MVCE that demonstrates all my attempts and contains all relevant code. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a method named `User.is_authenticated`. Inside `User.__init__`, though, you set an attribute with the same name.

```
self.is_authenticated = False
```

This overrides the method. Then, whenever you check `current_user.is_authenticated`, you are accessing the attribute that's always false.

You should remove the assignment from `__init__` and change `is_authenticated` to the following:

```
def is_authenticated(self):
    return True
```

If you need it to be dynamic for some reason, rename the attribute so it doesn't shadow the method.

```
def is_authenticated(self):
    return self._authenticated
```

---

Another problem is with your `load_user` function.

Instead of `filter`ing for `User.id==user_id`, you are `get`ting it. The user wasn't being returned because `load_user` is returning `User.query.get(True)` instead of `User.query.get(user_id)`.

If you make the following change, it will work:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    try:
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    except:
        return None
```

Comment: I figured it out. I think your answer was a definite part of my problem as well. I'll edit your answer to include my resolution and accept it. :)

Comment: I wanted to say "Thanks!" but that message wasn't long enough, so here's a message saying that instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to create is_authenticated field in Database
2. Flask-Login will take care of that